# Visual Basic conditional statements in a MessageBox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, messagebox, conditional-statements

I'm making this little program because I was bored and I ran across this problem. Kevin bacon never shows up, meaning that the ElseIf dialogResult.no doesn't become true when i do click no.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnMessage_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMessage.Click
    MessageBox.Show("I like Kevin Bacon.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If DialogResult.OK Then
        MessageBox.Show("You like Kevin Bacon.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        If DialogResult.OK Then
            MessageBox.Show("We all like Kevin Bacon.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            If DialogResult.OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("They all like Kevin Bacon.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                If DialogResult.OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Let's wait to see if Kevin Bacon will come to play.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                    If DialogResult.Yes Then
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000)
                        MessageBox.Show("Kevin bacon didn't show up... :(", "No Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                    ElseIf DialogResult.No Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Well too bad! Here's kevin bacon!", "Wild Bacon has appeared!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                        Form2.Show()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnStuff_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStuff.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: oh and Form2 is just a picture of Kevin Bacon. so just ignore that.

Comment: Nice, that's how I imagine proper VB code to look like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need declare a variable of type `DialogResult` and assign the result of your MessageBox to it. What you are doing now is looking at the `DialogResult` of your `Form` not your `MessageBox'

```
    Dim Result As DialogResult

    'Displays the MessageBox

    Result = MessageBox.Show("You like Kevin Bacon.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

    ' Gets the result of the MessageBox display.

    If Result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ok Then

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using MessageBox.Show as a statement when you should be using it as a function.  So instead of:

```
MessageBox.Show("You like Kevin Bacon.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
If DialogResult.OK Then
```

use:

```
If MessageBox.Show("You like Kevin Bacon.", "Bacon", MessageBoxButtons.OK) = DialogResult.OK Then
```

That sample line was taken from a WinForms app, but the principle would be the same for WPF and ASP.NET.